# Send email through VBSCRIPT

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have to send a simple mail to applicant on successfull submission of the form.What is the code in vb to do that?
I have been trying this..

```
function email()
    Set mailObj=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        mailObj.Subject="Hello"
        mailObj.From="abc@xyz.com"
        mailObj.To="123@456.com"
        mailObj.TextBody="text"
        mailObj.Send
    set mailObj=nothing
end function
```

Is there some problem in the code?Kindly rectify..

Comment: Are you facing any problem while running this? If so mention them. How are we going to understand whether you are facing any problems or errors if you don't mention everything clearly in the post ?

Comment: No but I am not receiving any mail in the email id specified in the To: column...There is no error while running this,just that i am unable to send email

Answer (score 3):

Use something like the following.

```
 Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
 objEmail.From = "fromsomeone@company.com"
 objEmail.To = "someone@company.com"

 objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
 objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
     "your.smtpserver.here"
 objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
 objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update

 objEmail.TextBody = "The body of the email"
 objEmail.Subject = "The subject"

 objEmail.Send
```

Comment: What is this your.smtpserver.here??
Mean what is to be written in place of this??

Comment: Here you put the IP or DNS name of the SMTP server you are going to use to send the email.